# Is there a way to repeat regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, regex-group

Test sample:

```
This is a test 234.990*2334 sample 123. 23423
```

What I have which works: `\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}`

Question 1: Is there a way to simplify it by asking the regex engine to repeat `\d{3}` twice like grouping it and repeating it etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a group around it to repeat it.

```
(?:\d{3}.){2}\d{4}
```